# What does the もて before a verb means?

Tags: grammar

What does the もて before a verb means?

I found this word in the dictionary http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MDEemphatic%20prefix (which only says it is an "emphatic verb prefix" and give no other information on it whatsoever)

I've no idea how it is used / whether it is used / or how to use it

Comment: (1) Please add examples.  (2) The link to WWWJDIC is broken.

Comment: もてあすぶ (which is a single verb all together)?

Comment: He probably means this entry:  もて (pref) (before a verb) (See もて囃す, もて扱う .1) emphatic prefix.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi i've edited the question, is the link ok now?

Comment: @Derek もとあすぶは ?

Comment: @Boaz yepp that

Comment: @Pacerier - I think he meant もてあそぶ which means "to play (around) with".

Woohoo, just noticed comments allow 'returns' now!

Comment: @istrasci: Luckily I was using Chrome and Opera all along, so it never bothered me. But good to know it's solved now. :)

Comment: @ist what do you
 mean allow 'returns'?

Comment: @Pacerier - If you were typing a comment and hit the Return/Enter key, it would automatically submit the comment.  This made it a horror to try to add any Japanese text, because you usually have to hit Enter to accept the input characters.

Comment: @istra cool, this is different behavior from other stackexchange sites

Comment: though to be sure, i initially never had a problem with the "Enter" key submitting too. what software are you using?

Comment: Firefox.  Enter was submitting on both XP and OSX.

Comment: @ist as in the software that is responsible for the japanese character input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like a rather rare prefix, really. I tried to count all the verbs that have it in my Kenkyusha dictionary (I could go for a larger one, but I didn't want rare verbs) and I've got these:

- もてあそぶ (sometimes in Kanji: 弄ぶ) - *to toy with something or someone*
- 持て余す - *to be too much* (especially: too much to handle)
- もてなす  (持て成す) - *to treat*, *to welcome*
- もてはやす (持て囃す) 持て囃す- *to extol*

Four verbs in a medium-sized dictionary, that's it. This "prefix" definitely isn't very productive, and you definitely can't use it with any verbs. In fact, it's just the first part of a tiny closed list of compound verbs that come as is. This is different from a productive verb prefix that can be used to create compounds ad-hoc such as あえて (e.g. in あえて言う *dare to say*, *go ahead and say*).

Another thing that makes もて different from a regular prefix is that it doesn't change the meaning of the following verb in a consistent manner. While あえて always adds the same element of daring, もて isn't simply intensifying all verbs in the same way. You can probably  say it's an intensifier in all the verbs in my list except for (持て成す), but the intensification works differently in any place and you can't predict the meaning of the compound verb by just knowing what the verb joined with もて means.